# Apache on my rPi LAMP box stopped working for no reason

Tags: linux, apache, cron, lamp, raspberry-pi4

I was editing /etc/crontab when things turned south. I have no idea why, and I rolled back my changes on the /etc/crontab file but apache is still messed up and I can't access local development websites hosted on this machine. When I run `systemctl status apache2.service` this is what I get:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-10-04 11:27:33 MDT; 6min ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 2413 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Oct 04 11:27:33 pidev.local systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 04 11:27:33 pidev.local systemd[2413]: apache2.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Oct 04 11:27:33 pidev.local systemd[2413]: apache2.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/sbin/apachectl: No such file or directory
Oct 04 11:27:33 pidev.local systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Oct 04 11:27:33 pidev.local systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 04 11:27:33 pidev.local systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Any ideas? I can't seem to trace what's wrong here.

Comment: after rolling back changes, you did restart the system, yes? (no need to reply). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I rebooted it a bunch of times. :-(